# How to use a custom style for a specific page in word press

Tags: css, wordpress, templates

My friends, I designed a WordPress plugin that I put in shortcode inside a blank page and it does the specified process, but my problem is that it does not follow the raw style that I designed and uses more than the default style of the WordPress theme. To solve this problem, I also used wp_head and wp_footer as templates, which solves the main problem, but there is another problem that due to its use, the main wp_enque header is not loaded in this case, and the styles and wp_localize are for ajax is used. They are not loaded after that. Styles and scripts can be added to the page manually, but wp_localize, which is for ajax transfers and handling, does not work this way.
Would you like a way to use wp_localize on a specific page without a default style?

```
<?php
```

/* Template Name: mypage*/

```
get_header('myheader');
echo do_shortcode("[LiteSpec id=man]"); 
get_footer('myfooter');
```

?>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks .... I want to use Ajax on a custom page. I use `wp _localize` for this. This function requires a handler as input, which is taken from `wp _enqueue`. The problem is that `wp _enqueue` does not load on the custom page.